# How to visualize sound?

Tags: c#, .net, audio

When music is playing how can i draw a wave?

Answer (score 4):

This should help you out:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SoundViewer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo project that will allow you to visualize sound waves in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SoundViewer.aspx

Comment: and how can i change mic to audio card??

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a graph and over time vary its height based on pitch, on volume, or just about any combination you may wish.  A standard is to vary the period based on frquency of the sound and height on amplitude.